# Export Websphere Application Server v7 Configuration

Tags: configuration, configuration-files, websphere-7

Is it possible to extract the websphere application server configuration from one server and import it into another?
I realise there's a Configuration Archive file, however that option is only available from within RATIONAL developer tool.
I have standalone websphere server instances, e.g. these servers are not defined within RATIONAL developer tools; which i need to export ALL their configuration settings to allow me to:-
a). Compare all configuration settings to ensure two instances have exactly the same config.
b). Allow me to export configuration from one server and import into another so that i know both are configured exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Configuration Archive functionality isn't restricted just to RAD.

You can do this via `wsadmin` scripting as well. See here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_atconfigarchive.html?lang=en

Comment: that is such good news, thanks very much, not sure how i missed this. is this only for version 8 and above? i shall investigate versions less than 8 as we are currently running on 7